# Создание цикла для отсчета билетов

Tags: java, циклы

Я новичок, учу `java` всего две недели, поэтому не слишком ругайтесь, если сильно туплю.

Учитель задал задание вывести отсчет билетов номерами с `200000 до 210000 и 220000 до 235000`.

Я написал двумя способами for и while. 
Метод for:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       for (int i = 200000; i <= 210000; i++) {
          System.out.println(i);
       }

        for (int l = 220000;  l <= 235000; l++) {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
}
```

И методом while

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int a = 200000;
        int b = 220000;

        while (a <= 210000) {
            System.out.println (a);
            a++;

        }
        while (b <= 235000) {
        System.out.println(b);
        b++;
        }
    }
}
```

Ответ приняли, но дополнили задание, чтобы отсчет был написан одним циклом с наименьшим количеством итераций.

Значит ли это, что я должен совместить оба кода при одном использовании `for`?

Если кто-то напишет, как это сделать, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Считать от a до b. Изначально а и б равны 200000 и 210000. Если б стало равно 210000, то изменить  их на 220000 и 235000 и продолжить итерацию

Comment: *одним циклом с наименьшим количеством итераций* Один однопроходный цикл, т.е. одна итерация. Правда, внутри 25 тыщ output-ов - но уж что просили, то и получите.

Comment: if (i > 210000 AND i < 220000) continue;

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант пропускать не нужные цифры они находятся в диапазоне от 210к до 220к

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       for (int i = 200000; i < 235000; i++) {
          if (i > 210000 && i < 220000) continue;
          System.out.println(i);
       }
    }
}
```

**Update:** Не увидел сразу

С минимальным количеством итераций

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int from = 210000;
        int to = 220000;

        int ticket = 200000;
        // Пример с for
        for (int i = 200000; i <= 235000; i++) {
            if (i == from + 1) i = to;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        // Пример с while
        to -= 1;
        while (ticket <= 235000) {
            System.out.println(ticket);
            if (ticket == from)
                ticket = to;
            ticket++;
        }
    }
}
```

Поправил условие как подсказал @Akina вместо i >= from на i = from

Comment: *`if (i >= from) i = to;`* ... и бесконечный цикл на 220000. Должно быть `if (i = from+1) i = to;`

Comment: *`if (i == from) i = to;`* 210000 не будет выведено. А в `while` наоборот, и там не будет выведено 220000.

Comment: @Akina забыл учесть инкрементацию

Comment: @Akina После этого будет бесконечный цикл на 220001.

Answer (score 0):

Я готов выполнить это задание <s>с 3 нот</s> за 15000 итераций:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int from = 220000;
        int to = 235000;

        for (int ticket = from; ticket <= to; ticket++) {
            if (ticket <= 230000) { // 200000 - 210000
                System.out.println(ticket-20000);
            }
            System.out.println(ticket);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересное решение=))) Но при этом пострадает порядок, хотя про него и в вопросе не сказано

Comment: @Walfter Да, не сказано ;) А если скажут, то надо просто результаты сложить в две переменные и вывести по очереди.

Comment: @Akina ОБА что?

Comment: @Akina 210к и 220к выводятся в первых двух строках моего письма.

Comment: Надо выводить от 200к, а не от 210к. См. задание. И в любом случае - из-за строгого неравенства последнее значение в первом диапазоне НЕ  будет выведено.

Comment: @Akina Ааа, точняк. Затупался. Тогда надо ``<=``, да. Спасибо.